# Why don't ruby methods have lexical scope?

Tags: ruby, closures

For example

```
def test
    a = "a is for apple"
    def inner_method
        a = "something" # this will refer to a different "a"
    end

    inner_method
    puts a
end
```

Are there any reasons for this? Blocks have lexical scope, so why don't methods? Is this going to be fixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because Ruby's methods aren't first class objects (as they would be in [IO](http://iolanguage.com/), for example). So when you define the inner method, what is the receiver? Presumably the method itself, or the binding or something, but Ruby doesn't have that deep of OO.

Anyway, it's unclear to me what you were expecting to happen in your example, were you wanting it to modify the local variable `a`? If so, a proc is a suitable substitute for a method.

```
def test
  a = "a is for apple"
  inner_method = lambda do
    a = "something"
  end

  a # => "a is for apple"
  inner_method.call
  a # => "something"
end

test
```

"[functional.rb](https://github.com/JoshCheek/deject/blob/ab885ff2afe62f258a32c99616c93a4ba9e24dab/lib/deject/functional.rb)" is a more extravagant example of this style of programming.

And "[lambda, proc, and Proc.new](https://web.archive.org/web/20111022133433/http://joshcheek.com/blog/1_lambda_proc_and_proc_new)" is a breakdown of Ruby's different types of closures.

Comment: It just seems out of place when everything else has lexical scope.

Comment: "Everything else"? Except for blocks, *nothing* has lexical scope. Not method bodies. Not class bodies. Not module bodies. Not script bodies. *Blocks* are the ones that are "out of place".

Comment: Scala's methods aren't first-class objects, either, yet inner methods close over their surrounding methods' environments. There is a much simpler reason why the "inner method" doesn't close over its outer method: because it *isn't* an "inner method". It's a definition of a global method.

Comment: I'm not sure what a global method is. Possibly a method on `Object`, but I don't think we can see enough context to conclude that is the target. There is some hidden variable that tracks where a variable gets defined. I think it's called `cbase`, based on [this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/compile.c#L5082), but I didn't go attempt to verify.

Comment: `class/def/module/etc` are a keyword DSL added on top of the object model, and things like `cbase` exist only to support it. Cases like this or `instance_eval` vs `instance_exec` only make sense with interpreter magic. But OP's expectations are reasonable, if methods were first class objects (or sugar for vars), this would work like they anticipated. The only way to make sense of what happens in cases like this, is to understand the object model (methods are stored in classes) and interpreter implementation details (eg it would also be reasonable to expect it to define a singleton method).

Comment: ruby * is not * lexically scoped. How blocks work in ruby is technically inconsistent, but is probably done that way so people can use #each in place of "for / in" without changing their code too much. Ruby's scoping is not one of the finer points of the language.