# Why can't I define a variable outside of a method and update from within a method?

Tags: ruby, scope, local-variables

Why does this example fail?

```
x = 100
y = 200

def my_method
  puts "Current x/y: #{x}, #{y}" # fails to find x and y
  x += 1 # fails to find x
  y += 1 # fails to find y
end
```

Comment: Ruby methods don't have lexical scope - here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089414/why-dont-ruby-methods-have-lexical-scope

Answer (score 2):

Variables within methods exist only within those methods. 
The variables `x` and `y` should be global:

```
$x = 100
$y = 200
```

Comment: What is the scope of the x and y at the very top?

Comment: @IHazABone You say the variables x and y should be defined with global scope (ie. '$x').  If the scope of the variables currently defined the way they are right now as the OP has written them are not global, then what scope are they?

Comment: When I look at the snippet, I see `x` and `y` defined "outside" of any methods, so I wouldn't understand why those variables aren't visible to `my_method`. I'm sure there are languages where the snippet actually works, so someone coming to Ruby with those backgrounds would probably be confused by the reasoning.

Comment: @SoylentGreen: Their scope is the scope wherever they were defined. If it was a class definition body, it's the class definition body scope. If it's the top level, it's the main scope for that file.

Comment: Global is overdoing it a bit. `@x = 100` is enough.

Comment: You are correct, but global is simply safe for multiple classes if he uses them. I was always taught that you might as well go big with global, so.

Comment: @Keikoku: the scope of a local variable is the body it is defined in. Method body, block body, class definition body. In this case, it's a script body.

Answer (score 2):

Methods in Ruby do not have lexical scope, i.e. they are not objects. In other words, the local variables declared outside of a method are simply not available by design.

Blocks work differently: they are in fact objects and also able to access local variables of the surrounding scope:

```
x = 5

increment_x = proc do
  x += 1
end

increment_x.call

puts x         # prints 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can , but it depends on what type of variable do you use.
There are 5 types of variables,

1. global variables
2. instance variables
3. class variables
4. local variables
5. constants.

You are trying to use local ones.
For doing what you want you can choose **global, instance or class variables**.

**The scope of a local variable ranges from class, module, def, or do to the corresponding end or from a block's opening brace to its close brace {}.**

Thats why your example doesn't work.

For reading http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm